# LogCat shows logs for an android app and does not for another one

Tags: android, logcat

I've installed two different android applications in my real device and in both I have

`<application android:debuggable="true" ...>` in AndroidManisfest.xml file.

Oddly, for one app the LogCat prints all actions and for the other the LogCat remains empty.
I can't realize why that is happening.

Help please.

Comment: Are you logging things in both applications?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Devices view in Eclipse by pressing ctrl+3 and write "devices".

When you launch each app, go to the Devices view and choose the device/app.
Now go back to the LogCat view and see if you see any logs.

This question has got zero to do with Worklight. I have edited the question accordingly.